# select image in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have an image field and would like to use to upload image (I have managed to do this part with `models.ImageField`) or to have selected an image in the database. How can I do it? I would like a similar interface or something like this:

[image]

Comment: In my experience, I suggest you to avoid Django admin for complex and elaborated interfaces. Use InlineModelAdmin (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to associate multiple instances of the Image model you created. In this way you can get a good result anyway. But if you need to work on a WP-link interface, then I suggest you to make an ad-hoc template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Filer for django.
It's a complete file managment tool where can upload and select images that are already uploaded.

[django-filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer)

And it looks quite similar to your example.

Once installed you only need to add

```
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField
```

to your `models.py` and change your `models.ImageField` to `FilerImageField` and Filer will do the rest.